# In R, when using named rows, can a sparse matrix column be added (concatenated) to another sparse matrix?

Tags: r, matrix, sparse-matrix, cbind

I have two sparse matrices, `m1` and `m2`:

```
> m1 <- Matrix(data=0,nrow=2, ncol=1, sparse=TRUE, dimnames=list(c("b","d"),NULL))
> m2 <- Matrix(data=0,nrow=2, ncol=1, sparse=TRUE, dimnames=list(c("a","b"),NULL))
> m1["b",1]<- 4
> m2["a",1]<- 5
> m1
2 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"

b 4
d .
> m2
2 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"

a 5
b .
>
```

and I want to `cbind()` them to make a sparse matrix like:

```
  [,1] [,2] 
a    .    5
b    4    .
d    .    .
```

however `cbind()` ignores the named rows:

```
> cbind(m1[,1],m2[,1])
  [,1] [,2]
b    4    5
d    0    0
```

is there some way to do this without a brute force loop?

Comment: It would just work if you match positions and names:

 m1 <- Matrix(data=0,nrow=4, ncol=1, sparse=TRUE, dimnames=list(c("a","b","c","d"),NULL))
 m2 <- Matrix(data=0,nrow=4, ncol=1, sparse=TRUE, dimnames=list(c("a","b","c","d"),NULL))
 m1["b",1]<- 4
 m2["a",1]<- 5
 cbind(m1[,1],m2[,1])

but I understand this is not an answer to your question..

Answer (score 2):

You should send the question to Martin Maechler, the author of much of the  Matrix package. There is a cBind function, but it does not at the moment recognize rownames, only dimensions, at least as far as I can tell (even when increasing the deparse.level argument to 2).